# creating a list of selected items in a grid View using C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I am working on an app in Windows Phone 8.1.
I have created a GridView control in which the items are multiple grids. the items in GridView are custom created. Now I want to add the selected items of a GridView to a list(in this case IList<>). below is the code

```
IList<GridViewItem> itemGrid = itemGridView.SelectedItems;
```

however I cannot do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting an error with this code? if so, could you post it?

Comment: you should add the error message you are getting to your question.

Comment: sure next time I will! for now the doubt is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cast<T>` method which works with `IEnumerable`:

```
IList<GridViewItem> itemGrid = itemGridView.SelectedItems.Cast<GridViewItem>().ToList();
```

Comment: Well it worked!
However the casting was supposed to be done into Grid type since my source items in GridView were of type Grid and also the list was supposed to be of type Grid.